# package of google app engine project

Tags: google-app-engine, salesforce, google-apps

HI I m new to google app engine,and I want to know is there an option in app engine to create a installer package of a project which can be deployed in other google app domains.So basically project will not be hosted publically but only for particular google app domains

An analogy I m looking here is salesforce package,where a developer can create a package url,through which package can be installed in other orgs. The project is not hosted publically. http://appexchange.salesforce.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can package your source easily.  The only variable that needs to change is in app.yaml application: field in python and appengine-web.xml in java.  This will allow you to deploy the app in other domains.

As far as the package url that isn't how App Engine works.  You can set your application to allow only certain domains to access it and provide an API for integrating it into another application, but that is different than Sales Force package url.

Answer (score 0):

When developing a Google App Engine application you don't have to specify the url of the project. So you can install and deploy your application to several organizations or even subprojects.

The only thing you need to set is the application name in the [app.yaml](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig) (in case you are using python) or [appengine-web.xml](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig) (for java)

So for developing an installer I would create a script that first asks the user for the name of the application they want to deploy to, modifying the configuration files accordingly, and then calls the normal appcfg.py installer.

Comment: Don't you hate it when you post an answer but someone basically beat you to it but Stack didn't send the notification.